# Link does not work as expected when Posting to Facebook Wall using App

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I finally made it possible to post on my pages Wall, and everything shows up as expected.

One problem though ...when you click the link, nothing happens. But if you copy and open the link in a new window, it redirects to the right page. Also, if you are not logged in to Facebook ...everything is fine.

The link has this redirection stuff going on:

http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=170600643029454&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hip-hop.dk%2Fevents%2F746%2Fdj-noize-em-nordic-dj-session&response_type=code&display=page

Does anyone know how to solve this?